# Forever app installation failure on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, I have NPM version 3.4.2-Oubuntu4, it states that it is the latest version. I get the following error when I try to install `forever`:

```
$ sudo npm install forever -g

winston@3.6.0: wanted: {"node":">= 12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've added the full error message? It looks like it is just a small part of it

Answer (score 1):

forever need a specific version of node to be install correctly

on your system you have node version 8.10.x installed and latest version of forever needed a version greater than 12

you have two solutions :

1. install an old version of forever (the version 3 is compatible with node 8) `sudo npm install -g forever@3.0.0`
2. upgrade your node version installed

for sample n utilities allow you to do it quickly

```
sudo npm install -g n 
n 12.x.x (wanted version)
```

Comment: It appears that there is still a compatibility issue that i do not understand npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
/usr/local/bin/forever -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
/usr/local/lib
└── forever@3.0.0

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /forever/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.13
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-203:~/explorer

Comment: npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
/usr/local/bin/forever -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
/usr/local/lib
└── forever@3.0.0

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /forever/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.13
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-203:~/explorer

Comment: yes you have a lot of module not compatible. have you try with npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: you also have `npm audit fix` that will try to fix dependencies version but be careful it will change version in package.json